# How to run a function that only does something if a value is not empty in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
 var analyst = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet Details").getRange(7,3).getValue();
```

How do I write a function that only pushes the event if name of the analyst is not empty?

```
iSheet.getRange(lowerBound+1,2,dumpL,21).setValues(whole)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Apps API has a built-in function to check if a cell is empty.  Check if it is empty and, if so, set your value.

```
var isCellBlank = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet Details").getRange(7,3).isBlank();

if(!isCellBlank) {
    iSheet.getRange(lowerBound+1,2,dumpL,21).setValues(whole);
}
```

The exclamation point in `if(!isCellBlank)` reverses its meaning, so it's going to execute the code in brackets if the cell is NOT blank.

Comment: I tried this but still, it gets all the events even if the cell is empty

Comment: @Nero is the range totally blank (no spaces, characters, etc)?  If so, .`isBlank()` should return true, causing `!isCellBlank` to be false.  If `isBlank()` is returning false (or perhaps `undefined`) there must be something in the cell or a problem in the object hierarchy.  Try running the script in debug mode and putting a breakpoint on the `if` statement to see its value at runtime.